# css expand with content in wordpress template - assistance request

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I have a PHP template but it seems to overlap the template (WordPress) when I add additional text. Any ideas? Code below:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Homepage Template
*/
?>

<?php get_header(); ?>
<div class="homecontent"></div>
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<div class="cleared"></div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! I pasted the code you linked to directly into your question. In the future, instead of posting links to your code, include it in your question in a code block.

Comment: You need to give a little more clarity on what it is you need assistance with. Its quite vague and difficult to understand what the problem is. Please could you elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide your CSS? I'm guessing that the problem is that you don't have a height on your div's.